# p4v command line submit changelist

Tags: perforce, p4v

Is there any way to use command line to submit a changelist already created with p4v? May I open command line in p4v? I have a huge changelist and p4v gets stuck when I right click on it to chose submit and I want to use command line or something else to submit it. When I say huge changelist I mean 170+ GB with more 300k files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to do it from a dos/terminal window. P4v doesn't accept command line commands. There is an option to "open command window here" in the File menu, but you still have to type in the command.

`p4 -c <workspace_name> -u <username> submit -c <changelist#>`

(don't use the <>) By default perforce assumes your workspace name is the name of your machine, so if your workspace is named something else, put it in

Comment: Note that if you use "open command window here" you won't need the -c <workspace_name> -u <username> as these will be set to the current connection you have in p4v (you can see them in the environment variables).

Answer (score 3):

In a shell (either Command prompt or some terminal window, depending on the OS), a simple `p4 submit -c changelist#` should do. If you did a typical install of p4v, then the p4 command line utility was installed as well. Otherwise you have to get it from the [Perforce website](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/p4.html). For a more detailed description call `p4 help submit`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an option in the GUI to print the equivalent commands to the message part on the bottom of the screen. I don't have a Perforce client here to hand but if you explore the Options you will probably find it.

Comment: I see the commands in the client, but I don't see where I can write commands.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to install the [p4 command line client](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/p4.html) as well. That's what I use.

Answer (score 0):

P4V does have a very limited command line interface, one of which is the option to "submit a specified file", but it only allows you to submit one file... not a changlist.

```
p4v -cmd "submit C:\path\to\file"
```

I think George posted your best command line option.... p4 submit -c

If you want to find out more information about the P4V commands, there is a blog post (link below) describing the command line interface of P4V.

http://blog.perforce.com/blog/?p=1928